# Reading a Bitmap from disk on a separate thread on Android

Tags: java, android

I want to defer the reading of a bitmap to another thread. I'm mainly concerned about concurrency issues since I'm kind of green on that subject, so I would like to know if this code has any potential flaws.

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    Bitmap threadBitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new BitmapTask().execute();
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(threadBitmap != null) {
                    // Assume bitmap has loaded and do something with it here
                }
            }

        });
    } 

    public class BitmapTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream in = null;

            try {
                in = getAssets().open("mybitmap.png");
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if(in != null) {
                        in.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            threadBitmap = result;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start reading of a bitmap?

1. If it starting in onCreate, you should use a progress bar while you load resources.
2. If it starting after some user interaction you can use default image for button and set new image in `onPostExecute()` methods. Your button should be class 
   instance variable of course.
3. And `try` block inside `finally` is ugly.

Comment: Ugly, but necessary I guess? How else would you close the InputStream? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: After `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);` Why not?

Comment: Well if the `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);` throws an exception then `in.close()` won't get called.

Comment: [BitmapFactory.decodeStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeStream%28java.io.InputStream%29)

Comment: Well I can't argue with facts :) It just seemed natural to me that it would throw an exception if the stream didn't represent a bitmap. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would implement a progress bar to inform the user of the image loading status to eliminate confusion to what it's going on.

Also, you could deactivate the button for as long as the thread is running. And reactivate it in `onPostExecute()`.